# A strange-seeming construction in Tolstoj

Tags: грамматика

In «Так что же нам делать?», Lev Nikolaevich wrote

«Я сижу на шее у человека, задавил его и требую, чтобы он вез меня, и, не слезая с него, уверяю себя и других, что я очень жалею и хочу облегчить его положение всеми возможными средствами, но только не тем, чтобы слезть с него.»

Normally Russian and English grammars agree completely, such that it's possible to translate using the same construction.  But here I'm baffled.  He switches from simple present to simple past and then back again (сижу...задавил...уверяю).

Translating directly into English, the construction doesn't work:  "I sit on a person's neck, crushed him and demand, that he carry me..."

I'd expect him to have written «сижу на шее у человекa, давя его, и требую...», which of course in English would be "I sit on a person's neck, crushing him, and demand that he carry me...".

Could someone explain?  If we were ever taught how to deal with such constructions, the intervening 50+ years have wiped out the memory.

Comment: "Задавая" is the form of the verb "задавать", not "задавить".

Comment: BTW. You can't form деепричастие of the present tense of the verb "задавить" at all. Only "задавив" (i.e. past tense) or "давя" (which is the form of "давить").

Comment: @user4419802: you can't form any present tense from any perfective verb.

Comment: The article name is «Так что же нам делать?».  Unlike English, in Russian only the first word in article/book name is capitalized.

Comment: I believe this translation would be closer: "I am sitting on person's neck, i have crushed him and i am demanding from him to carry me"... and so on. The times are present continious for сижу, past perfect for задавил, not simple present and simple past.

Comment: @Srv19  Generally in English, Present Progressive is used only for real rather than abstract situations.  Simple Present is used for abstract situations (and perhaps should be called Abstract Present instead).  

So "I am sitting on a person's neck" implies that not only are you doing it physically right now, but you don't know or don't want to reveal to the listener the identity of the owner of the neck.

Answer (score 9):

Russian language is not so strict about mixing past and present tense. Consider that Russian Past tense plays both English Simple Past and Present Perfect.

So you may think this sentence as *I sit, I have crushed, I demand* etc. For the sake of better translation, it's also possible to use just participle *crushing*, if you'd like to. There's no big difference here.

Comment: +1 on the note of English Present Perfect, especially considering that "задавил" is a perfect verb due to the prefix "за-".  The imperfect counterpart to it is "давил", which corresponds much more to English Past Indefinite, or even Past Continuous.

Comment: @DK As far as I understand, "choked" is even better here.

Comment: -1 for English Present Simple "I sit". I'm sitting would be correct

Comment: @user907860 Not, as far as I understand English. Tolstoy didn't talk about some real action, it's just a metaphor. There's no true "time setting"  here, so there's no reason to use continuous tense.

Comment: as far as I remember the rules, the is no exception for a metaphor  in the case of Present Simple. He says that he is sitting on the man's neck right now, not everyday, not from the time he was born etc. So the only correct tense here is the Present Continuous one.

Comment: @user907860 It is not about exceptions, it's about the meaning of the whole excerpt. "I sit on the neck" here denotes the life-style. Just find and read the whole paragraph, as TS cited only the end of it.

Comment: @user907860.  4419802 is correct.  Simple Present should perhaps be called Abstract Present instead, because it's only used to express abstract action.  Using it to express current action, e.g., "I drink the water" is an indicator that the speaker has an imperfect grasp of the language.  The same thing is NOT true of Simple Past ("I drank the water") or Simple Future ("I will drink the water").

Comment: @4419802.  I wasn't really concerned about how to translate, but about understanding the rule that Lev Nikolaevich used.  My training was fairly extensive -- 12 hours/day (8 class, 4 homework) 6 days/week for 2 years.  And then I read and spoke the language every day for 7+ years.  In all that time, I _never_ came across such a construction  before running into it in «Так что же нам делать?»  I was sure I'd be told it was a printing error, or an archaic construction, or slang, or a regionalism, but that it's just normal but rule-less?  That's quite the surprise!  Я бы _никогда_ не догодалась.

Comment: @4419802  _Consider that Russian Past tense plays both English Simple Past and Present Perfect._  I've always considered "present perfect" to be another mislabeling made out of an unhealthy respect for Latin.  It should really be called Abstract Past.  (Our principal grammar prof, V. I. Bondarenko, also considered it a poor choice of name, tho he didn't blame Latin.)

Comment: @MMacD,sorry, I didn't understand.Are you saying, that 4419802 is correct and at the same time you are saying, that `Using it to express current action, e.g., "I drink the water" is an indicator that the speaker has an imperfect grasp of the language`?But `I sit` in this situation is not an `abstract action`. It is a metaphor but in this metaphor Tolstoy is speaking about the definite situation: he is sitting on the man's neck. For instance, I can use a metaphor: I'm so confused, as if I'm going on the street without my pants. And 4419802 says that it should be `I go on the street`.Am I right?

Comment: @user907860 I'd say "As if I walked down the street", because you mean fully unreal action. Though in another context "As if I walk down the street" would be OK too.

Comment: yes, you are right, this can be considered as an unreal situation. Let me provide another one, `He is so confused, as if he is stealing money from old lady's purse`. This is more real, and what you will say about it. Should it be `I steal`? I mean the definite action, someone has put his hand into the purse and is trying to steal the wallet

Comment: @MMacD I'm a little surprised you haven't encountered such constructions earlier. There are tons of them. E.g. "_Прихожу_ я _вчера_ домой и _вижу_, что дверь настежь, а все деньги _пропали_" or "_В следующем году_ я _еду_ на курорт, а ты _будешь сидеть_ дома" etc.etc. Here is very dull and lengthy article on that matter: http://rusgram.narod.ru/1490-1515.html

Comment: @user907860 "As if he's stealing" = "I believe his hand is in her pocket right now". You _may_ choose continuous tense but only if you really _mean_ it. If you care to read Tolstoy's passage you will realize that he meant "I sit all my life", not "right now". And saying "I'm sitting all my life" is nearly the same as "Every single moment of my life I'm sitting, and sitting, and...". It simply has no sense, unless you really believe that someone is interested in every single moment.

Comment: no, he did not mean the sitting for all his life. He was talking about all his life, which he depicted with one metaphor, which stands for one situation (during some realistic period, a minute, an hour), where he is sitting at the neck. One cannot sit on someone's neck for all his life, as you said in one of the previous comments, then it should be `I sat`. You are contradicting yourself.

Comment: @user907860 One can _sit_ on someone's neck for all his life. What one can't do is _be sitting_ for all his life. You seem not to catch this.

Comment: yes, someone can **literally** sit for all his life on a neck, exactly as one can be walking on the street without his pants. And in the same approach I can justify use of almost any tense in English, because in my opinion someone *can*

Comment: and please, do not distort, what I've said. I definitely know, and I mentioned it previously here, that present continuous cannot be used in situations which last permanently, all life etc. I said that in this situation, about the sitting on the man's neck it is definitely unreal (you cannot sit for 50 years on a neck), so as **you said**, the translation must be `I sat`

Comment: @user907860 1. You can use any tense but _only if you mean_ it. Yet first you have to realize what every tense truly means. 2. I didn't say "I sat". You confuse metaphor and conditional. There's no condition in "I sit on the neck".

Comment: @user907860 Tolstoy wrote: "Я принадлежу к разряду тех людей... Я хочу помогать людям... Я сижу на шее у человека... Я всю свою жизнь провожу так..." Taken as a whole, it clearly means that he lived _all his life_ like this, until he realized that "в деньгах, в самых деньгах, в обладании ими есть что-то гадкое".

Comment: thank you for the notice of the absence of a conditional clause. This is my error, I will remember this

Comment: and yes, you are right about `sit` in this translation, I've read this excerpt from the book right now, and yes, he is talking about all his life. This was not clear from the citation provided by MMacD. I really don't know now, should I remove the comments above or not.

Comment: @user907860 Well, these comments are probably off-topic, as they discuss the subtleties of English, not Russian. Yet I hope they won't hurt anyone, so there's no need to wipe them.

Comment: @4419802 _Here is very dull and lengthy article on that matter: rusgram.narod.ru/1490-1515.html_  Благодарю! - I'll read that with interest!  But this _"Прихожу я вчера домой и вижу, что дверь настежь, а все деньги пропали"_, at least from my standpoint, isn't nearly such a blatant/troubling case: "Yesterday I come home and see that the door is standing open, and that all my money went away" (I'd actually use the past tense "vanished" or "disappeared", but they could be participles and I wanted to be clear that in this example the tense switch still has a parallel in English.)

Comment: @4419802  This one _"В следующем году я еду на курорт, а ты будешь сидеть дома"_ is perfectly ordinary-looking:  "Next year I'll go to a health resort but you'll sit at home" (I'd probably use present-progressive for both to capture the flavor more completely).  Exactly parallel constructions in both languages, which is what my experience has always been---until my brain came to a screeching halt reading Lev Nikolaevich's essay!

Comment: @907860 _For instance, I can use a metaphor: I'm so confused, as if I'm going on the street without my pants._  Since the basic question is cleared up, I'll just add a small note:  this wouldn't be metaphor, it'd be simile or analogy.  It'd be metaphor if you said, e.g. during a discussion, "I am naked" to mean you have no more objections/defences not that you are physically naked.  The way I keep them straight is:  "I am a cat" = metaphor; "I am cat-like" = simile.

Comment: @MMacD So what's the problem then? You can't mix present tense with past imperfective, yet perfective is OK. I say, both legal "Я иду по улице, _перехожу_ дорогу" and "Я иду по улице, _перешёл_ дорогу". Maybe you're a little confused with the meaning of "задавил"? Here it stands for "choked him (a bit)" not really "killed/cruhed/smashed" etc.

Comment: @MMacD "Я еду" = "I go". I could say "я поеду" (i.e. I'll go) but using present tense shows a strong intent here. Don't know if it's posiible in English: "Next year I go (i.e. for sure)".

Comment: @4419802  The problem was the switch from present to past _and back_.   In your _прихожу я вчера_ example, you start in the present to heighten the sense of immediacy, and then drop into past to emphasise that the money is still gone today.  That works perfectly in English too.  But Lev Nikolaevich's going back and forth doesn't work at all.

Comment: @4419802  As to the meaning of _задавил_, it's not a word I ever had occasion to use(!) so I had to look up the meaning.  But my good dictionaries disappeared along with my textbooks during one of the times I moved house in the past 48 years, and all I have now is an Oxford Concise.  It doesn't give "choke" as a translation for «задавить» in either direction, which is why I used "crushed".

Comment: @44198092  The поеду / еду distinction works in English too:  "I'll go to the health resort next year" [simple future, general intention] vs "I'm going [to go] to..." [the present-progressive "going" makes a stronger commitment about the future].  Another way in English, a more subtle shading, is to not use contractions:  "I will go" expresses an intention that's a bit more firm than "I'll go", and "I am going [to go]" is a little more committed than "I'm going [to go]".

Comment: @MMacD Don't take it as true "time switch". It's rather "a time agreement" between complete/incomplete actions (i.e. Russian perfective/imperfective verbs) which works both ways. English speaker would probably switch between simple/perfect to show that. That is, Tolstoy said something close to: I _am_ a bad guy (Я сижу на шее), and I _have_ bad things _done_ (задавил его), but I _want_ still more (и требую)... Of course, nothing here prohibits usage of present tense: "I _do_ bad things", except maybe the loss of expressivity.

Comment: @MMacD "Задавить" has three different meanings, yet all close to same-root verbs: "раздавить", "удавить", "подавить". Here it's a synonym to "удавить" - strangle, choke, asphyxiate. Consider also "удавка" (garrote), "удав" (boa constrictor).

Comment: Считая, что мой Оксфорд не хватает, купила, и только что получила, 1985-ое Смирницкого.  А нашла, что даже и Смирницкий не дает «choke» переводом «задавить»!  Сленг или жаргон, быть может?  The meanings Smirnitskij gives are the same as the ones in my Oxford:  crush, run over [with a vehicle].  Давиться/подавиться includes the meaning "choke", but of course that's not transitive.  Подавлять/ подавить are all in the "suppress/overpower/crush [resistance]" neighborhood, per Smirnitskij, as is раздавить.   Can the language really have changed so much in just 30 years?!?

Comment: @MMacD Bilingual dictionaries are not the things you can rely on. "Задавить" is something in between choking and crushing the throat. Quite often it is used to denote animal's attack. E.g. "The fox killed a chicken" -> "Лиса задавила (или задушила) цыплёнка". My book marks this as "colloquial", but it's not a slang, for sure. And it's quite old too. In modern language it rarely applies to human beings, but googling of "зверь задавил" would give you a plenty of hits in Russian part of Internet.

Comment: @MMacD `Считая, что мой Оксфорд не хватает` -> "Посчитав, что моего Оксфорда не хватает"; `1985-ое Смирницкого` -> "Смирницкого, издание 85-го года"; `А нашла` -> "А обнаружила"; `не дает «choke» переводом «задавить»` -> "не даёт перевода 'choke' к слову 'задавить'".

Comment: @user4419802   Thank you.  I purposefully started in present before switching to past because that works in English ("Reckoning that my Oxford isn't up to the job, I bought... But found....".  Why wouldn't it work in Russian in this case?  Is it more a style issue?

Comment: @user4419802 _Bilingual dictionaries are not the things you can rely on._  Fair enough.  We were taught that Smirnitskij is rock-solid, coming as it does (did?) from «Русский Язык» .  But I could bear having a decent Russian-only dictionary.  What's a good one?

Comment: @user4419802 А нашла -> "А обнаружила" Now you've really got me nervous. Обнаружить didn't look right to me, so I looked it up in Smirnitskij and then in a cheesy pocket Collins that my son gave me for Xmas donkey's years ago. Both say "display". Then I checked the Oxford and it gives as a second meaning "discover". Why that verb rather than наидти, which is given first for "find"?  (Looking at Smirnitskij again, I see it gives "discover" as a second meaning.  I need to get new glasses)

Comment: @MMacD (1) Grammatically both are OK, but there's a huge stylistical difference: simply informing vs. describing the past using some kind of "presence effect".

Comment: @MMacD (2) Well, the most useful books on my shelf are [this](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C) and [this one](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%90._%D0%90._%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: @MMacD (3) Well, maybe I was too harsh on it, but here "я нашла, что" sounds like both "I looked up" and "I found out" (the latter in a quite old-fashioned and bookish manner). This is a bit undesirable.

Comment: @MMacD `Both say "display". Then I checked the Oxford and it gives as a second meaning "discover"` The funny thing, but my book proposes the same. Such the academic stuff is; sometimes they move about 100 years in the past without noticing. Nowadays, "обнаружить" almost always means "to detect" or "to discover". "Обнаружить" as "to display / to put on show" is a rare "bookish" guest.